# SQL Distinct /Order By error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I've got a problem when using "order by" & "distinct" at the same time. For example, I have the following:

```
DECLARE @fieldSort varchar(100) = 'ref'

SELECT DISTINCT EXT_Design_Standard_ID
FROM EXT_Design_Standard_Change_Log
ORDER BY CASE 
     WHEN @fieldSort ='REF' THEN 
          EXT_Design_Standard_ID 
     END
```

I get the error of:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Anyone know how to sort this out?

Comment: < 30% acceptance for ~10 questions...

Answer (score 0):

Do the DISTINCT in a subselect and the ORDER BY in the outer select

```
SELECT * from (SELECT distinct... ) order by ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fieldSort varchar(100) = 'ref';

with cte As
(
SELECT distinct     EXT_Design_Standard_ID
from EXT_Design_Standard_Change_Log
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY  
    CASE WHEN @fieldSort ='REF'
    THEN EXT_Design_Standard_ID END
```

Or use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT EXT_Design_Standard_ID
FROM EXT_Design_Standard_Change_Log
GROUP BY EXT_Design_Standard_ID
ORDER BY  
    CASE WHEN @fieldSort ='REF'
    THEN EXT_Design_Standard_ID END
```